# Is my understanding of cyclic voltammetry correct?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, electrons, cyclic-voltammetry

So recently I've been roped into doing some CV and I'm trying to wrap my head around the fundamentals of the science behind it (and electrochemistry more generally! Bare in mind I'm very much not an electrochemist...). This is where I'm at:

- We have our three electrode setup, two of which are submerged in the same electrolyte solution: working electrode (WE), reference electrode (RE - Ag/AgCl in this example - contained in its own little unit with its own electrolyte solution; the contained RE unit is however submerged in the bulk electrolyte solution along with the WE and CE) and counter electrode (CE - Pt wire in this example).
- When we cycle through the voltages, we're measuring the electric potential of the working electrode relative to the reference electrode (which, handily, will always remain at 0V and thus the difference in volts between the WE and RE - the voltage - will always equal whatever the electric potential of the WE is).
- In order to polarise the WE (ie, either pump electrons into it or remove electrons from it) we use an external power source. We attempt to do the same with the RE but pumping electrons into it simply results in Ag being reduced, and removing electrons from it results in Ag being oxidised, and thus no net polarisation of the RE is possible (hence the 0V).
- Polarising the WE negatively (eg, -0.4V, -0.6V, etc) = pumping it full of electrons, which means those electrons are relatively high in energy and readily available to reduce anything at the WE surface.
- Polarising the WE positively (eg, +0.5V, +0.8V, etc) = removing electrons from it, which means the electrons that remain are relatively low in energy and thus electrons in things at the surface of the WE are likely to 'jump' into the WE, in the process oxidising whatever it is they're jumping from.

With all that in mind, here are my questions:

- When we're pumping electrons into/out from the WE, do these electrons come from/go to the Pt CE? Given Pt is very inert, this means something in the electrolyte solution must be being oxidised/reduced?
- What is the electric potential of the CE throughout the process? Say we've polarised the WE to +0.6V (ie, forcibly removed electrons from it), the RE remains at 0V (as it always does) - does the CE become -0.6V? After all, the electrons being removed from the WE have to go somewhere - presumably some would go to the RE as well as the CE, so the polarisation of the latter won't be the exact inverse of the WE?
- The RE is contained in its little unit with its own electrolyte solution. I've seen in diagrams that a porous frit separates the RE's electroyle solution from the bulk electrolyte solution that the WE and CE are submerged in. What can traverse this barrier? I assumed it would only be certain ions (so it would effectively act as a salt bridge as seen in normal galvanic/electrolytic cells), but the word porous implies that water as well as certain ions can pass through it?

Any and all help is appreciated! If you're not too sure on the questions I'd be very happy if you just weighed in on the CV understanding part, and if you only know one/some of the questions then that'd also be great :)

Comment: Besides your specific questions you may find this introduction useful;  Faulkner, L. R., "Understanding electrochemistry: Some distinctive concepts", Journal of Chemical Education 1983, 60, 262.

Comment: In addition to the comment by `@porphyrin`, have a look at «A Practical Beginner’s Guide to Cyclic Voltammetry» in J. Chem. Educ. 2018, 95, 2, 197-206 (https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jchemed.7b00361) which is an open access publication.

Comment: You have very good questions but most of your points are discussed on here: https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_happening_on_the_counter_electrode_of_an_electrochemical_cell

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you! I'll have a read through.

Comment: @Buttonwood Ah that looks very handy - thank you.

Comment: @M.Farooq Thank you for the link. I'm interested in your statement 'the rate of sweep felt by the working electrode should be the same as the counter electrode'. My understanding is that during a CV, an external power source (ie, potentiostat) forcibly polarises the working electrode, and it does this by forcing electrons into it - electrons which 'come' from the redox reactions at the counter electrode. Does your statement that the same sweep must be 'felt' by both electrodes just mean that for whatever happens at the WE, there must be an opposite but equal redox activity at the CE?

Comment: @Technocratic, Yes, exactly this is my current understanding. The number of electrons entering the WE, must equal the number of electron leaving the counter electrode. This is the beauty of electrochemistry. It is exact and quantitative.

Comment: The suggested J.Chem. Ed articles are must reads. You can also get hold of Laboratory Techniques in Electroanalytical Chemistry, Revised and Expanded
By Peter Kissinger, William R. Heineman. Very famous and way more friendlier than AJ Bard's book.